# java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required. javafx

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a Scene class from a fxml file in the path **src/interfaces/panels/**, and the file is called **StartUp.fxml**, but I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3230)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
        at tienda.TIENDA.start(TIENDA.java:30)
```

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        window=stage;
        String path = new File("src/interfaces/panels/StartUp.fxml").getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(path);//I added this just in case
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("src/interfaces/panels/StartUp.fxml"));//this is the problem
        su=new Scene(root);
        window.setScene(su);
        window.show();
    }
```

**EDIT: This was the solution**
**TIENDA** is the class, and the path is relative to the class

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        window=stage;
        var resource = TIENDA.class.getResource("../src/interfaces/panels/StartUp.fxml");//HERE
        System.out.println(resource);
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(resource);
        su=new Scene(root);
        window.setScene(su);
        window.show();
    }
```

Comment: You pass either a `null` or a malformed object to `FXML`. Likely the resource path cannot be resolved. Create a variable via `var resource = getClass().getResource("src/interfaces/panels/StartUp.fxml")`, I presume if you debug this then and check the variables you will find this to be true.

Comment: I printed the resource value, and it is null, so now I understand why the error happens, but then, why does getResource() return null?

Comment: Otherwise check paths and the actual location etc.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I didn't know I had to use getResource from the main class and put a relative path from there.